# objective-c: multiple class defintions in one .m file, and calling methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, class

I've defined two classes in an m file, the first subclassing UIView and the second UIViewController. The UIViewController is instantiated at some point, and the vc is who instantiates my first class.

the first class implements the touchesEnded method, to simulate a button. when the touchesEnded method is fired in the first class, is it possible to easily call a method defined in the 2nd class, without going into delegates and such?

I tried playing with selectors with no luck

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible to easily call a method defined in the 2nd class

Yes, assuming that you are creating an instance of the second class and calling the method on that instance.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of whether the two classes are subclasses of the same type, or in the same or different files, you need a reference to an instance of that class to call a method on it, or force it to perform a selector.

The proper OO way to do this is with delegates, but you could theoretically do something like pass a reference to view 2 into view 1 when you create the views.  If you create them in IB you could create outlets so they reference each other that way.

In short: Yes, it is possible and easy to do, but I can't give you too much in terms of specific code without a more specific example of your situation